# crop rectangle with certain border color and cetain background color JAVA

Tags: java, image, opencv, javacv

I have an Image with some rectangles inside it .. what i need is to crop only rectangles that have a red border and white background using (Java) or JavaCV.

for example i have an car image with license plate .. each letter at the license plate have red bordered rectangle around it and a white background.

what i am looking for is to crop each letter in a single image .. letters are identified by red bordered rectangle around each one and a white background.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Check out [BufferedImage#getData#getPixel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/Raster.html#getPixel(int,%20int,%20int[])). It might also be helpful to see a sample image

Comment: you should consider adding both [javacv] and [opencv] tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change color space to HSV

   ```
    IplImage* imgHSV = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img), 8, 3);
    cvCvtColor(img, imgHSV, CV_BGR2HSV);
   ```
2. Get only hue channel:

   ```
   cvSplit( imgHSV, h_plane, s_plane, v_plane, 0 );
   ```
3. Do the thresholding to find red color:

   ```
   cvInRangeS(h_plane, cvScalar(x, x, x), cvScalar(x, x, x), imgThreshed);
   ```

   x - range of red in HSV color model.

   After this you will have white and black image, where white color is a red color on your   original image (they should be of rectangle shape, as you said).
4. Then use cvFindContours function.

   ```
   int contoursCont = cvFindContours( imgThreshed, storage,&contours,sizeof(CvContour),CV_RETR_LIST,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,cvPoint(0,0));
   ```
5. To bound box (rectangle) use (for every contour):

   ```
   CvBox2D box = cvMinAreaRect2( @current_contour@,
                           CvMemStorage* storage CV_DEFAULT(NULL))
   ```

   To check the color of background calculate its histogram and check if values of bins are  only 255 and 0 (they are values of white and black colors).

Hope, that will be useful!

Answer (score 0):

You might try this:

1. Find a group of red pixels close to one another
2. Find all red pixels connected to these, bucket-fill style
3. Compute the bounding box of all the pixels found
4. Perhaps check whether the red pixels are all close to the rim of the bounding box
5. Check whether the interior of the box is mostly white

This should work as long as your boxes are not interrupted and do not overlap.